# Vue add or remove enclosing div

Tags: vuejs2

I have a html structure like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
          <somecontent>
          <someothercontent>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, depending on the layout, I want to remove the container div so the structure looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
          <somecontent>
          <someothercontent>
    </div>
</template>
```

Note that the div is completely added or removed, not just the class name. `v-if` doesn't work here because it would also show or hide the content that is enclosed by the div. What's the simplest solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use
 v-if ... v-else

```
<template>
    <div v-if="condition">
        <div class="container">
          <somecontent>
          <someothercontent>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div v-else>
       <somecontent>
       <someothercontent>
    </div>
</template>
```